# Add Visualforce chart to a dashboard

Tags: visualforce

I'd like to add a table to a dashboard to simply provide a list of Salesforce campaigns and the URL to their Salesforce record. I am not a developer so I've done very limited apex coding. Hoping this is pretty straightforward to just display text and active hyperlinks. Thank you.

```
Campaign Name1   Salesforce record URL
Campaign Name2   Salesforce record URL
Campaign Name3   Salesforce record URL
```

Comment: This sounds like a task that is achievable with a standard Salesforce report  component (not Visualforce). If you really need to display the literal URL, as opposed to just providing a link, a formula field could generate this value.

Comment: What are the criteria for displaying the list of Campaigns? Once you put a Visualforce page into a dashboard, you will lose filtering on the dashboard. So you should try for a solution that requires zero Apex and go with a report that pulls a list of Campaigns.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to be a developer to do this. Make a report that shows a list of Campaigns (grouped by some field because you'll need to do that to put it on a dashboard) and then put that table into your dashboard.

For more information, try this Trailhead module: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/reports_dashboards

Answer (score 0):

[image]

So, this is what I initially created. It displays the URLs, but they are not clickable URLs. If you click on the chart, it takes you to the source report. Is there a way to make the URLs actual clickable links from a dashboard component/chart?